# Quasinilpotent if and only if acts as nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume that $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear map from the $\mathbb{C}$ vector space $V$ to itself. Is it true that if $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ then for all $v\in V$ there exists $n$ such that $T^n(v)=0$?

Edit : $V$ is not assumed to be finite dimensional, so $T$ itself may not be nilpotent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If every eigenvalue of $A$ is zero, does this mean $A$ is a zero matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125622/if-every-eigenvalue-of-a-is-zero-does-this-mean-a-is-a-zero-matrix)

Comment: I don't think that link answers my question. I don't try to show that $T$ is nilpotent, also it may not be nilpotent (note that $V$ is not assumed to be finite dimensional).

Comment: $T$ nilpotent means that  $T^n=0$ for some $n\ge 1$, which trivially gives your result anyway.

Comment: If $T^n=0$, yes. But it may not be.

Comment: It certainly must be that $T^n=0$ if all eigenvalues are zero, since any nilpotent matrix $T$ satisfies $T^n=0$, where $n$ is the size. This is why it is called nilpotent.

Comment: Consider the derivative operator on $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Only eigenvalue is $0$ but it is not nilpotent.

Comment: Yes, indeed, after this edit the question is different.

Comment: I did not edit the question itself, I already said 4 comment above that $V$ is not assumed to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Are you aware that a bounded  operator on Hilbert space, for example, need not have any eigenvalues at all?

Comment: Yes, I am. Are you suggesting to take the $0$ map on $1$-dimensional $W$ and an operator without an eigenvalue $L:U\rightarrow U$ and $T=0\oplus L : W\oplus U\rightarrow W\oplus U$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that would answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you very much

Comment: The Volterra operator discussed here would be a more interesting example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_operator.  Note the definition of quasinilpotent is different, and probably more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, that page was the first one that I checked however I believe that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of that operator. Am I right?

Comment: That's right, but the spectrum is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes but that does not answer my question, right?

Comment: That's also correct.